# LINQ for use with MS Access Database - C#

Tags: c#, linq, ms-access

Does anyone know if you can use LINQ techniques for querying a Microsoft Access database?  In my online searches for this question, I have gotten mixed reviews.  Some have said it's 'sort of possible' while others say LINQ can only be used with an SQL server database.

Does anyone know the definitive answer on this?

Comment: LINQ is a broad term; what do *you* mean by that? LINQ-to-SQL? Entity Framework? or just LINQ generally? the C# / .NET regular LINQ stuff will work just fine against data *that cames from* (past tense) MS Access...

Comment: Okay, I haven't seen information on how to use it

Comment: Have you checked [this site](http://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/384/how-to-connect-to-and-query-a-ms-access-database-mdb-and-accdb)? Any problems using their solution?

Comment: -2??  You guys are rough!

Answer (score 0):

LINQtoSQL can only be used with a SQL Database.

Entity Framework can work with SQL or Access.
LINQtoEntities can work with the Entity Framework.

General LINQ methods can work with IEnumerables regardless of how they were populated.